# SyntaxError: invalid label parsing json response

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, rest

Im getting this response back from jquery from my WS request.

```
{
    "SkyWinResponse": {
        "statuscode": 0,
        "message": "ok\n ",
        "rowsaffected": 1,
        "results": {
            "result": {
                "@xsi.type": "member",
                "accountCreditLimit": 0,
                "accountNo": 1000001,
                "address1": "Annavägen 10",
                "addressChangeDate": "2013-04-12",
                "balance": 2068,
                "balanceCurrency": "kr",
                "certificateText": "PK",
                "climateCompensate": 2,
                "club": "UFK",
                "contactName": "Last, Andreas",
                "contactPhone": "090-123456",
                "countryCode": "SE",
                "countryNameLocalized": "Sverige",
                "createdDate": "2013-04-11",
                "credit": false,
                "dateOfBirth": "1971-05-04",
                "emailAddress": "first.last@ufk.nu",
                "firstJumpDate": "2013-04-27",
                "firstName": "First",
                "gender": "M",
                "hideAccountInRequest": false,
                "honorary": false,
                "infoViaEmail": true,
                "instructorText": "HL HM KL",
                "internalNo": 1,
                "jumpNo": 0,
                "lastName": "Nylund",
                "lastUpd": "2013-05-18 15:58:23.0",
                "licenseType": "C",
                "markedForLabel": false,
                "memberList": false,
                "memberListOverride": true,
                "memberNo": 20878,
                "memberType": "M",
                "nationalityCode": "SE",
                "nationalityNameLocalized": "Sverige",
                "permanentCredit": false,
                "pilot": false,
                "postCode": 91342,
                "postTown": "Obbola",
                "studentJumpNo": 0,
                "supporter": false,
                "userId": "Linda",
                "verifiedLicense": true,
                "video": false,
                "weight": 100,
                "weightUnit": "kg",
                "year": 2013
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try to parse this i only get invalid label. Any sugestion how to read each entry entry:value and display them in a html page.

This the code im trying to run.

$(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://fake.server.se/skywin-ws-1.4.0/rest/skywin/member/getMember?memberNo=20878&_type=json',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(SkyWinResponse){
                      $.each(data.SkyWinResponse.results.result, function(i, item)
              {
                 $('#response').append(i + " : " + item + "
");
              });
                    }
                });
            })

Comment: Can you show you effort of code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your JSON is valid. Are you trying to do something like this:

```
 $.each(data.SkyWinResponse.results.result, function(i, item)
 {
     $('#response').append(i + " : " + item + "<br>");
 });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZGMY/)

Comment: I get this from debug in console.

Comment: try changing `function(SkyWinResponse)` to `function(data)`

Comment: post a link to a JSFiddle or something similar, so I can help

Comment: ok so the problem here is that in order to abide by the cross domain policy, you used jsonp, but the web service is returning json data. So, if you can either modify the web service or get your requesting page on the same domain, that would be a start